# ERROR: Invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ debugging homework problem

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and am having a hard time debugging this. Any idea why I am getting this error? The upper function is supposed to take in a pointer to a C-string as an argument, iterate through each character in the string and convert it to uppercase. Also, how can I get my function to return the string in uppercase?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

string upper(char* some_string){

    for (int i=0; i < strlen(some_string); ++i){
        toupper(some_string[i]);
        cout << some_string[i];
    
    }

    return "Done"
}

int main(){

std::string word;

cout << "Enter a string: ";
cin >> word;

upper(word.c_str());


}
```

Comment: A C-string is a `const char*`, an array of `char` which are each individually `const`. You cannot mutate one in-place. I'm curious why not write this function to actually take a `std::string` argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make the argument `const char*` because the function doesn't modify the string.
- Apply `toupper()` to what should be printed. (`toupper()` returns `int`, so the result should be casted to `char` to have it be printed as characters)
- Add a semicolon after `return "Done"`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

string upper(const char* some_string){ // use const char*

    for (int i=0; i < strlen(some_string); ++i){
        cout << static_cast<char>(toupper(some_string[i])); // apply toupper() to what to print
    
    }

    return "Done"; // add a semicolon
}

int main(){

    std::string word;

    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin >> word;

    upper(word.c_str());


}
```